# C++11 constexpr compatibility implementation

Tags: c++, c++11

In a [project](https://github.com/wasthishelpful/softbloks), I use the CMake module [WriteCompilerDetectionHeader](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/module/WriteCompilerDetectionHeader.html) to detect if C++11 features are available or not. The module generate a file with compatibility implementations for some features like `static_assert`: if the feature is available, the macro declared for the feature expands to that feature; it expands to some fallback otherwise.

The feature `constexpr` has no compatibility implementation. I tried to provide one and ended up with a double implementation: one for constexpr variables and one for constexpr functions.

In cmake file:

```
write_compiler_detection_header(
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo-compilerdetection.h"
    PREFIX Foo
    COMPILERS
        GNU
        MSVC
    FEATURES
        cxx_constexpr
)
```

In global header:

```
#include "foo-compilerdetection.h"

#ifdef Foo_COMPILER_CXX_CONSTEXPR
#   define Foo_CONSTEXPR_FUNCTION constexpr
#   define Foo_CONSTEXPR_OBJECT constexpr
#else
#   define Foo_CONSTEXPR_FUNCTION inline
#   define Foo_CONSTEXPR_OBJECT const
#endif
```

So for variables `constexpr` will be replaced with the qualifier `const` and for functions it will be replaced with the qualifier `inline`.

Are these substitutions adequat? Would an other qualifier or combination or qualifiers suit better and possibly work for both variables and functions?

Comment: `Are these substitutions adequat?` it depends on how you use those `constexpr` functions/variables; if you e.g. use the result of a `constexpr` function as a template argument, `inline` will not suffice

Comment: In C++11, constexpr member functions were const too. But that it isn't true anymore with C++14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is not that simple. `constexpr` is computed during compilation. `const` and `inline` are not.

I would say that for `constexpr` variable you have to consider two possibilities: `const` (which you used) and preprocessor macro (ie #define PI 3.14). One is great when it comes to respecting scopes, debugging etc, while the other is strictly compile-time.
When it comes to `constexpr` functions it's a bit more tricky. Such a function CAN be computed at compile time but does NOT HAVE TO. If you are pursuing compile-time evaluation you should consider templates and preprocessor (I know macros are evil but...). If we are discussing functions which should be evaluated at run-time, then inline or templates are your best shot.

Preprocessor macros are the only substitutions I know of for `constexpr` which can be used in `switch` statement (as `case` labels) or in array allocation ( `int tab[5];` )